# Using string in xslt apply-template select attribute

Tags: xslt

I have a string that contains a xpath query and it will be passed as a parameter or included from external source i don't know right now but it is dynamic that's sure.

I want to use this string in select attribute of apply-templates command.

```
  <!--this is external xml file to be queried.-->
  <xsl:variable name="v" select="document('foo.xml')"></xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/Selector">
    <!--this is our variable = query-->
    <xsl:variable name="xpathquery" select="string(@select)" />

    <!--i want to say this!-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$v/$xpathquery" mode="ui" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template mode="ui" match="*">
    <foo></foo>
  </xsl:template>
```

I hope i could explain it. Thanks.

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: Saxon 9 so it supports 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0 i guess.

Comment: You'll probably need XSLT3 for this. I've not had much experience with it myself, but this might be useful: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate

Comment: Thanks buddy. Theoratically it seems helpful but unfortunately Saxon 9 Home Edition does not support XSLT 3.0.

Comment: You need some sort of `evaluation()` function, which is only supported as an extension by some XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processors and is standard in XSLT 3.0.

Comment: You could also consider a two step transformation where the first stylesheet outputs a second with the right path and which you can then apply in a separate step.